# Where can I find a version Control branch naming guide?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tfs, azure-devops, version-control

Where can I find a guide on version control branch naming? I read that on [TFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server) it's better to take a final decision [before creating it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819542/261010). Did it improve in recent years? I mean in the flexibility of branch renaming?

It would be great to study a number of different version control layouts before taking this decision. Do you know any helpful web links for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Git branching strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops)**:

Keep your branch strategy simple. Build your strategy from these three concepts:

- Use feature branches for all new features and bug fixes.
- Merge feature branches into the main branch using pull requests.
- Keep a high quality, up-to-date main branch.

Use a consistent naming convention for your feature branches to identify the work done in the branch. You can also include other information in the branch name, such as who created the branch.

Some suggestions for naming your feature branches:

- users/username/description
- users/username/workitem
- bugfix/description
- feature/feature-name
- feature/feature-area/feature-name
- hotfix/description

About renaming old branches, please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#rename-old-branches).

**[TFVC branching strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc?view=azure-devops)**

Unlike Git branches, which are repository scoped, TFVC branches are path scoped and not as lightweight. Set your bar for creating branches high and only branch when you have a need for code or release isolation.